# Identify agent jobs missing on secondary replicas

Tags: sql, sql-server, content-management-system

I'm trying to setup a process that will check the agent jobs on all servers in an availability group and report back any that might be missing from secondary replicas.

I have CMS setup with all servers from the AG and can run a query for agent jobs across the replicas, but I only want to return jobs that are on some servers but not all of them.

I wrote a query to get this information by using COUNT() but because the query results are grouped by server, this isn't working. I also tried to put the results in a temporary table to see if this would help, but that doesn't seem to have made much of a difference.

There are four servers in the AG and the following query should return the name of any jobs that aren't on all four servers, but because it seems to return the server name too it isn't recognising them as the same Job.

```
CREATE TABLE #jobs (
    JobName NVARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO #jobs
SELECT name JobName
FROM sysjobs 

SELECT * 
FROM #jobs
GROUP BY JobName
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY JobName

DROP TABLE #jobs
```

The query as it stands would throw out a result set such as below:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------+
| ServerName |                 JobName                  |
+------------+------------------------------------------+
| ServerA    | DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL |
| ServerA    | OutputFile Cleanup                       |
| ServerB    | DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL |
| ServerB    | IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES           |
| ServerC    | DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL |
| ServerB    | IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES           |
| ServerD    | DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL |
| ServerD    | Output File Cleanup                      |
+------------+------------------------------------------+
```

The job DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL exists for all four servers so I don't want this one returned, but because of the implicit servername column which comes from the CMS connection it doesn't recognise them as the same value.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the content of the sysjob table ?

Comment: It's the standard output from any sysjobs table so I'm not sure what it is you need?  The table has a lot of columns too so would be difficult to put an output here that you could make sense of. Do you want a sample output from my query rather than the standard sysjobs table?

Comment: Since your temp table has only one column, your query result can't have two columns.

Comment: @WolfgangKais what is "it"? the query you used to get the job name only selects one column:  `SELECT name JobName FROM sysjobs`

Comment: @BrianPressler Yes, that's what I meant. So how can the query "throw out a result set such as below" (with 2 columns including the `ServerName`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get around it another way. I've now setup a table on my CMS server and I have a stored procedure that will populate the table with details on agent jobs from all servers in the AG. 
From there I can then run the following query and it works like a charm:

```
SELECT ServerName
       ,JobName
FROM AgentJobs
WHERE JobName IN(
                    SELECT JobName
                    FROM AgentJobs
                    WHERE JobCategory = 'Production'
                    GROUP BY JobName
                    HAVING COUNT(*) < 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

As GMB mentioned you will need to extract part of the "name" field.

I suggest splitting the string into ServerName and JobName.

Assuming the name is seperated by - like in your example your code could look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE #jobs (
ServerName NVARCHAR(128)    
,JobName NVARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO #jobs
SELECT 
LEFT(name,CHARINDEX('-',name)-1) AS ServerName --Takes the Part left of the first -
, RIGHT(name,LEN(name) - CHARINDEX('-',name)) AS JobName --Takes the Part right of the first -
FROM sysjobs 

SELECT JobName 
FROM #jobs
GROUP BY JobName
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY JobName

DROP TABLE #jobs
```

Comment: My apologies, I've note represented the output from my script very well. It isn't outputting a single string as shown above. I needed to obscure the server name so I'm getting two different columns return, the server name and then the job name. When I run my query it isn't ignoring the server name column so is treating all results as seperate.

Comment: Okay. So you want to group by JobName and count them but also want to see what ServerNames those jobs show up right?

Comment: I think the thing that might be tripping everyone up is that it doesn't return the server name and job name as a single string. They are two different columns, but the query seems to run on each servers results individually rather than treating them as a single result set.

Answer (score 0):

So want a query that returns all the `JobName`s that have less than 4 entries. There is not point creating a temporary table, just query directly the `sysjobs` table, like  :

```
SELECT name  
FROM sysjobs
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm querying four servers at once through CMS. Because of the servername that seems to come in with the query it doesn't recognise them as the same job name. If I run your query I get the following results:                                                                                                            
ServerA DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL
ServerB DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL
ServerC DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL
ServerD DBA DatabaseBackup - AG_DATABASES - FULL

Comment: @Trinity3Sixty ok then it means that we need to extract a part of the `name` field. Can you please update your question with some sample data of what can be found in your `sysjobs` table so I can update my query ?

Comment: Updated question with sample output to illustrate the issue better. Many thanks for taking the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS is always inserting the server name followed by the job name delimited with a dash surrounded by spaces... you could parse out the server names with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #jobs
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' - ', name),LEN(name)) , ' - ', '') JobName
FROM sysjobs
```

Comment: It isn't returning a single, delimited row. It is returning two columns, the server name and job name. The server name is not requested by my query but is returned by defauly on a CMS query. It looks like any query is still treating the results from each server as a separate entity and only presents them as a single result set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it" isn't returning a single delimited row.  The `name` field of `sysjobs` is a single field, so it's not clear to me what you are trying to say.

Comment: The "query" isn't returning only the name field from sysjobs. The query returns two columns, server and sysjobs.name, which is typical of a CMS query. The problem I was having is that my query wasn't being run on the results of the CMS query as a whole but seemed to be running against each server's result set individually. Because of this it would still return all rows because it didn't recognise the same jobs on different servers as the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the STUFF() function to put all the Server Names in one Column and only count the Job Names.

```
SELECT JobName, STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CAST([ServerName] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM sysjobs 
    WHERE results.JobNames = sysjobs.JobNames
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,1,'') AS ServerNames 
FROM #jobs results
GROUP BY JobName
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
ORDER BY JobName
```

Comment: The server name and job name are returning as separate result columns. It is not returning them together in a single field. It seems like the results are being treated as seperate result sets and are only displayed as a single results set after any query has executed.